# Can't Ctrl-C a script after controlling it from another terminal

Tags: kill, background-process, signals

I'm running `blah.sh` in one terminal. Then in another terminal, I'm running a script that suspends and later continues `blah.sh`:

```bash
...

script_id=`pidof -x blah.sh`
kill -s SIGSTOP $script_id

...

script_id=`pidof -x blah.sh`
kill -s SIGCONT $script_id
```

After this, `blah.sh` is pushed into the background; I have to type `fg` in its terminal before I can stop it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

Is there any way to automatically foreground `blah.sh` in its terminal after sending it the `SIGCONT`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to automatically foreground `blah.sh` in its terminal after sending it the `SIGCONT`?

Depending on what you need `SIGSTOP` for in the first place, you may or may not be able to achieve what you want.

---

#### Analysis

This is what I think happens in your case:

1. Job control is enabled in the shell where you start `blah.sh`. The shell starts the process in a separate process group and notifies the terminal the process group is now the foreground process group. This way the shell puts itself in the background and the process runs in the foreground.
2. When you `kill -s STOP` the process (by typing in another terminal), the process stops and the shell receives `SIGCHLD` automatically. This signal means "at least one of your children has been stopped or terminated; it's time to check on your children and react".
3. The shell reacts to `SIGCHLD`, it sees the child stopped, so it puts itself to the foreground by setting its own process group as the foreground process group for the terminal. Note this is the exact mechanism that would put the shell in the foreground if you sent `SIGTSTP` instead of `SIGSTOP`. E.g. if you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> in the terminal where the process runs then the foreground process group would receive `SIGTSTP`; this means the process but not the shell; it's `SIGCHLD` that causes the shell to react.
4. The shell is now in the foreground, it prints its prompt and waits for your input.
5. When you `kill -s CONT` the process, the process resumes. There is no mechanism similar to `SIGCHLD` that would cause the shell to react. The shell is unaware and does not change the foreground process group for the terminal. In effect the shell is still formally in the foreground and the process is still formally in the background.

One may think it's enough to ignore the prompt and stop interacting with the shell. In general: no. The process in the background will receive `SIGTTIN` if it tries to read from the terminal (which is most likely its stdin). Depending on the settings of the terminal (`stty tostop`) the process in the background will or will not receive `SIGTTOU` if it tries to write to the terminal (which is most likely its stdout and stderr). The default action upon `SIGTTIN` or `SIGTTOU` is to stop the process. Besides, even if the process didn't stop upon trying to read, the shell is still reading from the same terminal, so interacting with the process would be hard because of the shell "stealing" input.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> makes the terminal driver send `SIGINT` to the foreground process group. If the process in question is in the background then it won't get the signal.

Typing `fg` (instead of sending `SIGCONT` from another terminal) works well because `fg` is a shell builtin, so it's really the shell who handles `fg`. Now the shell knows you want to put the process in the foreground, so it alters its own behavior (stops reading from the terminal) and sets the foreground process group accordingly before sending `SIGCONT` to the process group of the process.

If your reason for stopping the process is a wish to interact with the shell then you should resume the process by interacting with the shell, i.e. by invoking `fg` there.

---

#### Possible solution

**However *if* your reason for stopping the process has nothing to do with the shell (e.g. you just want the process to stop computing) then you should change the way you start the process: disable job control in the shell**. This is what is going to happen:

1. **You run `set +m; blah.sh`.** `set +m` disables job control. When the shell starts `blah.sh`, it puts the process in the process group of the shell. This process group is and will will be the foreground process group all the time.
2. When you `kill -s STOP` the process (by typing in another terminal), the process stops and the shell receives `SIGCHLD` automatically.
3. The shell reacts to `SIGCHLD`. It wants to know if the child has terminated and it's time to resume interaction with the user. The shell sees the child stopped, not terminated; and because job control is disabled, the shell does not resume interaction with the user in these circumstances.
4. The shell and the process are in the foreground. The shell does not attempt to read, does not attempt to write; the process is stopped. They just sit there.
5. When you `kill -s CONT` the process, the process resumes. The shell is unaware but it doesn't matter, as it only waits for the process to terminate eventually and has nothing else to do.

---

#### Notes

- Technically the solution is not a "way to automatically foreground `blah.sh` in its terminal". `blah.sh` is in the foreground all the time and there is no need to "automatically foreground" it.
- Because `blah.sh` is in the foreground all the time, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will send `SIGTERM` to it even if it's stopped at the time. Stopped `blah.sh` will only react to `SIGTERM` after it gets `SIGCONT`. Note sending `SIGSTOP` to sole `blah.sh` does not imply sending `SIGSTOP` to its descendants, the descendants will most likely react to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> immediately.
- As sending `SIGSTOP` to sole `blah.sh` does not imply sending `SIGSTOP` to its descendants, you may consider sending `SIGSTOP` (and then `SIGCONT`) to the entire process group `blah.sh` is in. Each descendant will also be in the group, unless it's deliberately put in another process group for some reason. See `man 1 kill` where is says that "negative PID values may be used to choose whole process groups".

  Normally (I mean when job control in the shell is enabled) you should expect `blah.sh` and its descendants to be in a process group with PGID equal to the PID of `blah.sh`. In our solution (when job control is disabled) you should expect `blah.sh` and its descendants to be in the same process group as the shell; the PGID may or may not be equal to the PID of the shell.
- `set +m; blah.sh; set -m` looks promising if you want to automatically re-enable job control after `blah.sh` exits, but if you interrupt this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> when `blah.sh` is running then `set -m` won't be executed. Some trap(s) could probably handle this scenario reliably, but I won't elaborate.
- When job control is disabled, the shell ignores `SIGTSTP`. Processes started by the shell (e.g. `blah.sh`) will also ignore it; their descendants will also ignore it (unless some process deliberately chooses not to ignore). This means you should not expect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to work.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that. Only the shell can manage the foreground applications. Consider a scenario where your shell have couple of applications running in the background, and from another terminal you send `SIGCONT` to few of those applications. What do you expect to happen?

If your only intent is to remove one step, then instead of running `kill -s SIGCONT $script_id` and then run `fg`, you can just run `fg`. `fg` already sends `SIGCONT` to the background process, no need to send the signal explicitly using the `kill` command.